# Datagridview shows system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text: using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have a `Richtextbox` where user will update the data in a `SQL database`. The updated data will then be shown in a datagridview. However, the updated value will have a  `system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text:` at the front of the updated data, instead of the updated data itself. I've read threads such as [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167924/c-sharp-with-mysql-insert-parameters) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492019/update-statement-in-mysql-using-c-sharp) but I am unsure on how to implement it in my case. Below is my code:

**Update data - Form 1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Savertb.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Rtbdata SET Exterior='" + RichTextBox1 + "'", sqlConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
        this.Hide();
      }
```

**Insert Updated data in datagridview - Form 2**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Savertb.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Rtbdata", sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Close();
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implicitly calling `RichTextBox.ToString()` method which returns class name.
Use `Text` property

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Rtbdata SET Exterior='" + RichTextBox1.Text + "'", sqlConnection);
```

And take a look at parameterized sql command, it is save and convinient. Currently your code is subject to sql injection attack.